# modifying post meta from plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function awepop_show_views($singular = "view", $plural = "views", $before = "This post has: ") 
 {
    global $post;
    $current_views = awepop_get_view_count();

    $views_text = $before . $current_views . " ";

    if ($current_views == 1) {
        $views_text .= $singular;
    }
    else {
        $views_text .= $plural;
    }
    return $views_text;
 }

 function awepop_append_to_meta($meta){
    return $meta[] = awepop_show_views();
 }

 add_filter( 'the_meta_key', 'awepop_append_to_meta' );
```

I am trying to embed post views into post meta. I search alot but couldn't find the appropriate filter for post meta. please advice how can i embed my view count into post meta

Comment: For info purposes, check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23512958/1908141)

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking to `init` and using `update_post_meta`. For example, this is how you could increment your post views:

```
function my_update_postmeta() {
    global $post;
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, my_meta_key, $my_meta_value + 1 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_update_postmeta' );
```

Note: You would put `my_update_postmeta()` in your page or post template.

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta